# How to make my own select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wish to make my own select.

Actually my select looks like this :

[image]

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5tcyttg/)

and is it coded like this :

```
<p>Title</p>
<form>
    <input type="color" onchange="colorisPanneau(value);pageSuivante();" name="coloris_panneau" list="liste_color3" id="coloris_panneau" value="#C5B9A9" class="formc" style="height:24px;width:202px;">
    <datalist id="liste_color3">
        <option value="#FFFFFF">
        <option value="#999999">
        <option value="#000000">
        <option value="#582810">
    </datalist>
</form>
```

And i want to make it look like that :

### [image: combobox then]

How can i do this ?

What do i need to do to be able to personalize the interface in my `combobox` ?

Where can i find documentation to be able to do so ?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: both images are same, please correct

Comment: plenty of documentation on the net for you

Comment: @Pranav Patel Corrected

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @madalinivascu : i usually find documentation but for this subject i cant find the right words to type in google. Do you have any links for these documentations ?

Comment: @madalinivascu jsfiddle added to the post [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5tcyttg/)

Comment: as far as I know you cannot style or modify  `<datalist>`  tag... better to use some plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datalist cannot be modified with css, even if you could with some css-magic, you could never get multiple items inside of the datalist options. The only solution is to create a select box from scratch.

I was bored so I made you something you can start with:

```js
$('html').on("click", function(e) {
  $('.color-picker').removeClass('open');
});
$(document).on("click", ".color-value", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if ($('.color-picker').hasClass('open')) {
    $('.color-picker').removeClass('open');
  } else {
    $('.color-picker').addClass('open');
  }
});
$(document).on("click", ".list-item", function() {
  var color = $(this).data('color');
  $('#color-input').val(color);
  $('.color-value').html($(this).html());

  //This is now the value of your hidden input field
  $('#value').html(color);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.color-picker {
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #666;
  background: #FFF;
}

.open {
  overflow: visible;
  ;
}

.list {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-top: none;
  background: #FFF;
}

.list-item {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list-item:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.list-item>span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.list-item>span:first-child {
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.color-value {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="color-picker">
  <input id="color-input" type="hidden" name="coloris_panneau" value="" />
  <div class="color-value list-item">Select your color</div>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-item" data-color="#edae0e">
      <span style="background:#edae0e;"></span>
      <span>Yellow</span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item" data-color="#ff0000">
      <span style="background:#ff0000;"></span>
      <span>Red</span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item" data-color="#336699">
      <span style="background:#336699;"></span>
      <span>Blue</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is all i needed to start :) Thank you again !